# iOS: Custom location on a device

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

I have a location aware app that I am trying to test and the simulator isn't updating my location when I do Debug>Location>Custom Location and enter latitude and longitude coordinates .  However, the app is working fine on the phone.  Is there a way to enter GPS coordinates (latitude, longitude) to change my current location on my device?

Comment: Tried the usual quitting and restarting Xcode / Simulator ?

Comment: Yeah, I had been trying on iPhone 4s, 5, and 6 with no luck.  Just tried it on the iPhone 5s and its working.  Deleted the app from simulator on other devices and re-ran.  It works fine now, weird!

Comment: Reset content and settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When faced with such problems and you have no other solution then go to File menu of the simulator and reset its contents and settings. Then quit and restart both Xcode and the Simulator.